# Split cursor results in template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to generate a template with something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>A B C D</li>
 <li>E F G H</li>
</ul>
```

The data i'm providing to the template is a cursor that has 8 rows (one for each letter).

I know I could do a fetch and split the results in groups of 4, but if I'm not mistaken, the fetch is less efficient, if e.g. I update the value of A to 1, it reloads everything.

Any suggestion on how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: as far as I know, if `fetch()` is considered less efficient, it is for tasks where you don't require to really fetch the data, like a `cursor.count()`. The most known example is `if(Collection.findOne)` versus `if(Collection.find().count()>0)`. Since you display the data, I am not sure it makes a difference.

Comment: The whole point of reactive programming is to have the data be live. These kinds of in-place updates are blazingly fast, pun intended. Are you also trying to make these page elements non-reactive? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197247/how-do-i-make-a-meteor-helper-non-reactive As far as returning the data in groups of 4, you can have your helper return an array of arrays, where each outer array element contains an array of 4 elements.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for the reply. I suppose you are talking about the Template.registerHelper? How would you do that? I usually apply the helpers at an individual level, and what I return is not html stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<template name="outer">
  <ul>
    {{#each list}}
      {{> quadItem }}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="quadItem">
  <li>{{#each quad}}{{item}} {{/each}}</li>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.outer.helpers({
  list: function(){
    var arrayOfQuads = [];
    var array = myCollection.find().fetch();
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 4 ){
      arrayOfQuads.push(array.slice(i,i+3));
    }
    return arrayOfQuads;
  }
});

Template.quadItem.helpers({
  quad: function(){
    return this;  // data context should be one row of arrayOfQuads
  },
  item: function(){
    return this; // data context should be one element of a quad
  }
});
```

This is very quick and dirty, I'm sure it can be made more elegant.
For example see [how to make an array element selectable by index in blaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389414/meteor-blaze-select-a-specific-item-by-the-array-index).